# PHP: Validating form and displaying alert

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have a registration form in which i have a field login name. I want unique login name for every user so whenever user click a button i want to check database. If the login name entered by user is already present, i want to display an alert box asking him to try another login name. I wrote the following code.

```
if($login != '')
{
$query = "Select LoginName from register where LoginName='".$login."'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if($result)
{
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
alert("Login name exist");
</script>
<?php
}
else
{
insert into database
}
}
```

The problem here is every time it shows me an alert for the name already exists.It never goes into the else part.
Please help me about this

Comment: Before using that code in a productive environment you might want to take a look at what [SQL-Injection](http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysql-php-sql-injection.php) is and how to prevent it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first when you fetch data then count $rows array 
check if count is greater that 0 then u display error msg "username already exists"

so put if condition and in else write insert data

Enjoy :)

Answer (score 5):

The $result returned by mysql_query($query) will exist even if no rows are returned. It will only fail if the query is invalid or contains an error, and cannot be executed.

Try using the following:

```
if( mysql_num_rows($result) > 0 )
```

mysql_num_rows will return the number of rows that your query returned.

Friendly reminder: Don't forget to sanitize your user input to prevent SQL Injection.

Answer (score 0):

Your flow should be like this:

```
<?php
if($login != ''){
  $query = "Select LoginName from register where LoginName='".$login."'";
  $result = mysql_query($query);
  if($result){
    if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
?>
        <!-- LoginName already exists, do something here -->
        <script type="text/javascript">
          alert("Login name exist");
        </script>
<?php
   }
   else {
     // LoginName avaialable
     // your logic for registering user goes here
   }
 }
 else
 {
   // query not executed, handle this issue properly
 }
}
```

Comment: @user1400633: You should give some favor by an upvote atleast!

Answer (score 0):

check for  if($result['LoginName]){
}